# Having 2 separated components for table and pagination in angular 7

Tags: angular, pagination

I have worked on a table with pagination, sort and filter properties based on this link: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview . Now I want to make a separated component for pagination interacting with table component. I mean when the buttons of pagination are clicked, they work correctly in order to change the "items per page" or next page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i implemented it this way:

separate pagination component:

```
export class PaginatorConfigurableExample {
  // MatPaginator Inputs
  @Input('length') length: number;
  @Input('pageSize') pageSize: number;
  @Input('pageSizeOptions') pageSizeOptions: number[]; 

  @Output('page') page: EventEmitter<PageEvent> = new EventEmitter();

  setPageSizeOptions(setPageSizeOptionsInput: string) {
    this.pageSizeOptions = setPageSizeOptionsInput.split(',').map(str => +str);
  }
  setPage(event){
    this.page.emit(event);
  }
}
```

it's html:

```
<mat-paginator  [length]="length"
                [pageSize]="pageSize"
                [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
                (page)="setPage($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

parent table component:

```
export class StudentsComponent {
  displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChild('paginator') paginator: MatPaginator;
   /**
   * Set the paginator after the view init since this component will
   * be able to query its view for the initialized paginator.
   */
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
  onPaginationChange(event){
    this.dataSource.paginator.length = event.length; 
    this.dataSource.paginator.pageSize = event.pageSize; 
    this.dataSource.paginator.pageIndex = event.pageIndex; 
  }
}

export interface Element {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
  {position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'},
  {position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg'},
  {position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al'},
  {position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si'},
  {position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P'},
  {position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S'},
  {position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl'},
  {position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar'},
  {position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K'},
  {position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca'},
];
```

parent html:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
  <paginator-configurable-example #paginator
                                  length=10
                                  pageSize=10
                                  [pageSizeOptions] = "[5, 10, 25, 100]"
                                  (page)="onPaginationChange($event)"
  >
  </paginator-configurable-example>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ch2nmh).